# How to merge two vectors according to the original indices?

Tags: r, vector, merge

I was hoping to get some help over this problem. I have a vector `X` with 2,000 elements such that:

```
X<- c("A12","B5","B8","B19","A32","A25","B11","A2","A41","B51"......)
```

I extracted the IDs from the vector(`A` IDs and `B` IDs) separately. Now I have two vectors, `A` and `B`. This step is necessary because the process of obtaining `A_values` and `B_values` is different, so I needed to separate the two IDs into two vectors:

```
A<-c("A12","A32","A25","A2","A41".....)
B<-c("B5","B8","B19","B11","B51"....)
```

After this I obtained the values corresponding to their ids:

```
A_values <- c(15,21,22,6,2....)
B_values <-c(3,14,16,25,13....)
```

Now my problem is to merge the `A_values` and `B_values` vectors according to the original indices of Ids as they were in the original vector `X`. The new `X_values` vector should be:

```
X_values<-c(15,3,14,16,21,22,25,6,2,25,13.....)
```

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a named vector and then subset them using `X` :

```
c(setNames(A_values, A), setNames(B_values, B))[X]
#A12  B5  B8 B19 A32 A25 B11  A2 A41 B51 
# 15   3  14  16  21  22  25   6   2  13
```

Use `unname` or `as.numeric`/`as.integer` to remove the names if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `match`ing index concatenated for 'A', 'B'

```
c(A_values, B_values)[match(X, c(A, B))]
#[1] 15  3 14 16 21 22 25  6  2 13
```

#### data

```
X<- c("A12","B5","B8","B19","A32","A25","B11","A2","A41","B51")
A<-c("A12","A32","A25","A2","A41")
B<-c("B5","B8","B19","B11","B51")
A_values <- c(15,21,22,6,2)
B_values <- c(3,14,16,25,13)
```